# Fetching logs from Android Studio Application to be sent by email

Tags: java, android

I am trying to fetch the logs from a user app to be sent over to us by e-mail.

We're going to production and we want the user to be able to sent the logs to us in case the app crashes, so we could have a better understanding of what's been causing it.

Now, we've tried some codes so far but they seem to be outdated with the newest android security updates and it can only be done if using a "system app" and no longer if it's a user app.

I have recently seen an app that does it, though. An app on playstore. So I'm not sure if there's a way to get around the permissions or not.

The code I'm using is described bellow:

**MainActivity:**

public static long currentTimeMil;
public static File fileMain;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Context c = getApplicationContext();


    if ( isExternalStorageWritable() ) {

        File appDirectory = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MyPersonalAppFolder" );
        File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/logs" );
        currentTimeMil = System.currentTimeMillis();
        fileMain = new File( logDirectory.getAbsolutePath(), "logcat_" + currentTimeMil + ".txt" );

        // create app folder
        if ( !appDirectory.exists() ) {
            appDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // create log folder
        if ( !logDirectory.exists() ) {
            logDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        // clear the previous logcat and then write the new one to the file
        try {
            
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -c");
            process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -f " + fileMain);
        
            System.out.println("--------- SUCCESSFULLY WROTE TO FILE -------------");
            
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if ( isExternalStorageReadable() ) {
        // only readable
    } else {
        // not accessible
    }



    Button button1 =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Context c = getApplicationContext();

            String filename="logcat_"+Long.toString(MainActivity.currentTimeMil) + ".txt\n";
            File filelocation = new File(fileMain.getAbsolutePath());
            System.out.println(filelocation.getAbsolutePath());
            Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(Objects.requireNonNull(c),
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", filelocation);


            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            // set the type to 'email'
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            emailIntent .setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            String to[] = {"myemail@gmail.com"};
            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
            // the attachment
            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileUri);
            // the mail subject
            emailIntent .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");

            Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share File");

            List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = c.getPackageManager()
                    .queryIntentActivities(chooser, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

            for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                c.grantUriPermission(packageName, fileUri, Intent
                        .FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            }

            startActivity(chooser);

        }
    });
}


/* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if ( Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals( state ) ||
            Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals( state ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

**Android Manifest:**

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**I also created a xml folder with the following:**

```
  <?xml version ="1.0" encoding ="utf-8"?><!--  Learn More about how to use App Actions: https://developer.android.com/guide/actions/index.html -->
    <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
    </paths>
```

However, whenever I try to attach the files, it says it couldn't attach it and the errors I am getting are (resumed):

```
W/applicationtes: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mLoadedApkAssets:Landroid/util/LruCache; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->countLiveReferences(Ljava/util/Collection;)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->mCachedApkAssets:Landroid/util/ArrayMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->countLiveReferences(Ljava/util/Collection;)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getAdjustedDisplay(ILandroid/content/res/Resources;)Landroid/view/Display; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/hardware/display/DisplayManagerGlobal;->getCompatibleDisplay(ILandroid/content/res/Resources;)Landroid/view/Display; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getConfiguration()Landroid/content/res/Configuration; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getDisplayMetrics()Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Landroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;->DEFAULT_DISPLAY_ADJUSTMENTS:Landroid/view/DisplayAdjustments; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getDisplayMetrics(ILandroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;)Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getDisplayMetrics(ILandroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;)Landroid/util/DisplayMetrics; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getAdjustedDisplay(ILandroid/view/DisplayAdjustments;)Landroid/view/Display; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Landroid/app/ResourcesManager;->getResources(Landroid/os/IBinder;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/content/res/Configuration;Landroid/content/res/CompatibilityInfo;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/util/List;)Landroid/content/res/Resources; (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/applicationtes: Accessing hidden method Landroid/content/res/ResourcesKey;-><init>(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;ILandroid/content/res/Configuration;Landroid/content/res/CompatibilityInfo;[Landroid/content/res/loader/ResourcesLoader;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
I/chatty: uid=10453(com.example.myapplicationtest) identical 1 line
white_tick
eyes
raised_hands


E/Gmail: ComposeActivity:Error adding attachment
    fzd: FileNotFoundException when openAssetFileDescriptor.
```

I print the full path of the file created and it returns me this:

```
I/System.out: /storage/emulated/0/MyPersonalAppFolder/logs/logcat_1629716550168.txt
```

I know it might be a silly and noob question, but I can't find an answer online.

Comment: Not sure if tagging 'iOS' was a mistake or not, you've only mentioned Android / AndroidStudio in your question. Why not use one of the many third party solutions that do this already rather than wasting time building / testing your own? Both Crashlytics and Sentry have free plans and have been tested for a very long time

Comment: You cannot create your own directories on /storage/emulated/0 anymore. Try to create them in one of the public directories like /storage/emulated/0/Documents.

Comment: `appDirectory.mkdir();` There you go wrong by not checking the return value. It might fail and it fails and you are unaware. Better: `if (!appDirectory.mkdir()) return;` Also display a Toast to inform the user.

Comment: `File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/logs" );` No good  Better: `File logDirectory = new File( appDirectory,  "logs" );` Change all the others too.

Comment: Tied to the first comment, you should be using a logging wrapper such as Timber. There are plenty of recipes for getting Timber to log both to Logcat and to some remote destination of your choice.